# Code igniter prepending db prefix in table aliases

Tags: codeigniter, prefix, table-alias

I have configured code igniter to use db prefix.

At all other places it is working as expected but while creating table aliases it is prepending db prefix.

Code is as under:-

```
$this->db->from('table_a');
$this->db->join('table_b', 'table_a.id = table_b.a_id', 'left');
-----
$this->db->join('table_b as tablebAlias', 'table_c.id = tablebAlias.a_id', 'left');
```

Assuming my dbprefix is set to value 'foo'.

Final query which is getting executed is as under:-

```
Select * From foo_table_a left join foo_table_b on foo_table_a.id = foo_table_b.a_id
--- left join foo_table_b as tablebAlias on foo_table_c.id = foo_tablebAlias.a_id
```

Any help will be highly appreciable.

Thanks,
Jatin

Comment: And what is your question?? isn't it working as it is expected here

Comment: Would creating the Aliases with same preffix not be a suitable solution?

Comment: its a bug http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/126699/ . See @Christian's answer for the proper way to handle this if you must use dbprefix

Comment: @raheel -- Sorry if I was not able to explain it properly.

Comment: @Robin -- Ya it will work but it is kind of dirty hack ;)

Answer (score 9):

I found out that manual queries ignore table prefix. I also found out that there is a way to add table prefix to manual queries:

In config/database.php

One can do this:

```
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = "feed_";  
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = "{PRE}";
```

So that this can be done:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM {PRE}item";  
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
```

The {PRE} becomes feed_.

But swap_pre is not config.php which leads me to think that this is CI 2.0 feature.