# CodeIgniter or PHP prepend "sq" to table name, throws error

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In my local test environment, I uploaded information to tables using POST data no problem. I'm doing some testing on a live domain now on my host's servers, and am getting an error when using the same techniques.

The table is called `User_Information`, and I know it exists by checking phpMyAdmin. It was created using script.

Here in brief is the **code being used** to insert information to the table, using CodeIgniter framework. This is a summary, and am certain that the syntax of the true code is fine:

```
['database' library is already autoloaded and connected]

$first = $this->input->post('firstname');
$last = $this->input->post('lastname');
$email = $this->input->post('email');
$city = $this->input->post('city');
$state = $this->input->post('state');

$insert = array(
                    'First_Name' => $first,
                    'Last_Name' => $last,
                    'Email' => $email,
                    'etc' => $etc,
                );

$this->db->insert('User_Information', $insert);
```

And **the error** being thrown:

```
Error Number: 1146

Table 'myDatabase.sqUser_Information' doesn't exist

INSERT INTO `sqUser_Information` (`First_Name`, `Last_Name`, `Email`, `etc`) 
    VALUES ('Leonhard', 'Euler', 'Elias@euler.com', 'Select One')

Filename: models/Process_form.php

Line Number: 56
```

**The issue** is the value getting submitted for the table name -- from the error, it looks like it is looking for a table called `sqUser_Information` instead of the provided `User_Information`. I don't know where the 'sq' is coming from, or why it is getting prepended to my table, nor have I yet been able to find other similar situations online.

**I would like** to be able to access and insert data into my table, but cannot do so at the moment because of this faulty name being passed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Code igniter prepending db prefix in table aliases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548950/code-igniter-prepending-db-prefix-in-table-aliases)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Codeigniter, you are allowed to set a database table prefix. Check the file `application/config/database.php` and check the setting `$db['default']['dbprefix']`

Just delete the field and make sure it looks like

```
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
```

You can read more about codeigniter [database configuration here](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html).

If the field is already set to an empty string, it's possible you mistyped it when you created the table. Hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect. I was unaware of this setting, and there was indeed an 'sq' prefixed.